# Problems with fread/malloc

Tags: c, malloc, fread

```
FILE *infp, *outfp;
infp = fopen(argv[2], "r"); 

int len;
char *text;
fseek(infp, 0, SEEK_END); 
len = ftell(infp);
printf("%d\n", len);

if ((text = (char *) malloc(500000000)) == NULL)
{
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating memory\n");
        exit(1);
}
fread(text, len, 1, infp);
text[len] = '\0';
fclose(infp);
printf("Text = %s,  Address = %u\n", text, text);
```

returns

```
138
Text = ,  Address = 3794927632
```

I'm not sure why text isn't printing anything. Am I using fread wrong somehow?

Comment: Don't cast `malloc()` it's ugly and superfluos. And why `malloc()` such a huge ammount to use `len` bytes only, that doesn't make sense. It indicates that your code has bugs but you don't care.

Comment: You forget to rewind after `ftell`

Comment: actually we're told to assume 500mb for input file.

Comment: **Always** check the result of functions which might encounter an error! You do not even included the most basic error checking on your file functions.

Comment: If `len + 1 > 500000000`, code writes outside `text[]`.  Better allocate space needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After

```
fseek(infp, 0, SEEK_END);
```

`infp` points to the end of the file. You need to rewind the file.

```
rewind(infp);
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/rewind/ for additional info.

Comment: @user1869558, I suspect you meant to use `argv[1]`, not `argv[2]` in the call to `fopen`.

Comment: @user1869558 I too suspect that, please check the value of `argc` too before accessing `argv` and check my answer, you also didn't make sure `fopen()` returned a non-`NULL` pointer.

Comment: There was a check fopen() which I didn't include here. The problem I think was the rewind, and &text I used by accident instead of just text. When the instructor demonstrated ftell and fseek to find length, he neglected to show rewind as well...

Comment: @user1869558, as the answer by iharob shows, you can use `fseek` to rewind the file too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset the file position with `rewind()` or [`fseek(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseek.3.html) like this

```
FILE *infp;
FILE *outfp;
int length;
char *text;

if ((infp = fopen(argv[2], "r")) == NULL)
{
     fprintf(stderr, "Error openning `%s'\n", argv[2]);
     return -1;
}

fseek(infp, 0L, SEEK_END); 
len = ftell(infp);
/* reset position */
fseek(infp, 0L, SEEK_SET); /* essentially rewind(infp); */

printf("%d\n", length);
if ((text = malloc(length + 1)) == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating memory\n");
    return -1;
}

if (fread(text, 1, length, infp) == length)
{
    text[length] = '\0';

    printf("Text = %s,  Address = %u\n", text, text);
    free(text); /* never forget to `free' */
}
else
{
    free(text);
    text = NULL:
}
fclose(infp);
```

You also should

1. Check the return value of `fopen()`, you never check if the file was actually opened which I think is the main problem.
2. Allocate only the necessary space.
3. Ensure that `fread()` didn't fail.
4. Swap [`fread(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fwrite.3.html)'s size parameters, first is the element size and then the number of elements

   ```
   size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
   ```

   and the return value should be equal to `nmemb`, read the manual page at the link above.

Comment: Minor: length should be `long` as that is the type returned by `ftell()`.